# Booting Windows 11 breaks wifi (RTL8822CE) on 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot

I have a W11 partition that I rarely use, I only use it to update the BIOS.

Every time I use Windows, when I reboot (or shutdown) and go back to Ubuntu, the wifi chip is not detected:

```
rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to setup chip information
rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info
rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to download firmware
```

Last time it happened to me the issue went away after some messing with the system (but I don't really know what fixed it tho).

Can you help me understanding why it happens and what can I do to get wifi working again?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because Windows doesn't really shutdown. The feature is called "Fast Startup", it should be disabled if you use Windows with other OS's in dual-boot.

Comment: So disabling windows fast boot should be enough?

Comment: That's correct.